# How to center images and a slider in one line

Tags: html, css

I would like to have 3 buttons in the middle and a slider on the right side, these on the same line. The problem is that when I center the buttons and float the slider to the right, the buttons are not in the middle anymore. So it looks like this (ignore the top slider):

[image]

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.music-buttons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.volume-control {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" class="volume-control">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="music-buttons" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
  <img class="music-buttons" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
  <img class="music-buttons" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
</div>
```

It might be a mess, but I was just trying out stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this CSS code :

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
}

.music-buttons{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.volume-control{
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 22px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="div-range">
    <input type="range" class="volume-control">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="music-buttons" src="../icons/skip-start-circle.svg">
    <img class="music-buttons" src="../icons/play-circle.svg">
    <img class="music-buttons" src="../icons/skip-end-circle.svg">  
  </div>
```

Comment: This works, but it tends to be less tolerant when it comes to responsive behavior. You could see overlap on small screens, for example. Flexbox is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
}

.music-buttons{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.volume-control{
  text-align: center;   
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img class="music-buttons" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/skip-to-start--v1.png">
        <img class="music-buttons" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/pause--v1.png">
        <img class="music-buttons" src="https://img.icons8.com/external-kiranshastry-lineal-kiranshastry/64/000000/external-skip-multimedia-kiranshastry-lineal-kiranshastry.png"> 
        <input type="range" class="volume-control">
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question (which I admit isn't entirely clear).